# array_multisort $FILES array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is the result of a file uploading input.
The array $FILES looks like this:

```
 Array (
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20180131023939.JPG
                    [1] => 20180131024005.JPG
                    [2] => 20180131024027.jpg
                    [3] => 20180131023722.JPG
                    [4] => 20180131023913.JPG
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                    [4] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpzJ6Avh
                    [1] => /data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpMHduDZ
                    [2] => /data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpiSohMH
                    [3] => /data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpOoAJWp
                    [4] => /data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpdr9n87
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2461635
                    [1] => 402525
                    [2] => 1383589
                    [3] => 1154849
                    [4] => 441203
                )

        )

)
```

I want the entire array sorted by name. In this example *20180131023722.JPG* should have the index of 0 after the sort. The other values should also sort accordingly..

array_multisort should be used but I don't know how..

Comment: Please, add a language-specific tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting arrays with this structure is very difficult. The transpose array is easy to sort. The array then has this structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => "20180131023939.JPG",
    'type' => "image/jpeg",
    'tmp_name' => "/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpzJ6Avh",
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 2461635,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (..
```

After sorting, transposition can be done again if the original structure is needed.

```
function array_transpose(array $array) {
  $newArr = [];
  foreach($array as $keyRow => $subArr) {
    foreach($subArr as $keyCol => $value) $newArr[$keyCol][$keyRow] = $value;
  }
  return $newArr;
}

//test data
$files = [
  'name' => ['20180131023939.JPG','20180131024005.JPG',
          '20180131024027.jpg','20180131023722.JPG','20180131023913.JPG'],
  'type'  => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg'],
  'tmp_name' => ['/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpzJ6Avh',
           '/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpMHduDZ',
           '/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpiSohMH',
           '/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpOoAJWp',
           '/data/sites/web/mersbe/tmp/phpdr9n87'],
  'error' => [0,0,0,0,0],
  'size' => [2461635,402525,1383589,1154849,441203]
];

$arr = array_transpose($files);

//sort by name asc
usort($arr, function($a,$b){return $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];});

//transpose back
$files = array_transpose($arr);
```